# How do I get the HTTP status code for a failed CORS request in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cors

I'm sending a request with jQuery's `$.ajax` method and want to print the HTTP status code when the request did not succeed.

When the POST/GET request itself fails with an error, all is fine and the error can be easily printed within the `error` callback.
However, when the browser sends a preflight OPTIONS request and this fails (e.g. with a 404, because the URL is wrong), then the callback does not print anything useful.

For the sample below, the following is printed to the console:

```
response: [object Object]
response.status: 0
response.statusText: error
response.responseText: undefined
status: error
error:
```

When I check the network request in the browser debugger, the following response headers are received:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 130
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Vary: Origin
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.0 Python/3.6.9
Date: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 13:01:47 GMT
```

How can I get the 404 status code in order to print a useful error message? At the moment, the only thing I can do is print `unknown error`, which does not show that the problem is actually a 404.

Sample code:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';

$(function() {
  $('#file-upload').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const files = $(this).prop('files');
    const file = files && files.length && files[0];

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      let encoded = e && e.target && e.target.result.toString().replace(/^data:(.*,)?/, '');

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/upload',
        data: JSON.stringify({data: encoded}),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        processData: true,

        success: (response) => {
          console.log('success');
        },

        error: (response, status, error) => {
          console.log("response: " + response);
          console.log("response.status: " + response.status);
          console.log("response.statusText: " + response.statusText);
          console.log("response.responseText: " + response.responseText);
          console.log("status: " + status);
          console.log("error: " + error);
        },

        complete: () => {
          $(this).val('');
        },
      });
    };

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: It's not the same port (`8000` vs. `3000`) so it shouldn't work

Comment: I don't understand, the backend is running on 8000, the frontend on 3000. When the backend returns an error from the GET request itself, not already from the OPTIONS request, everything works fine.

Comment: You cannot access the response when a CORS error occurs. This is by design for security reasons. If you own both the client and server in this scenario simply add CORS headers to the response you send

Comment: I own both, the client and the server and I do set correct CORS headers. However, it seems like the browser sends a OPTIONS request to `/foo/bar`, which might not exist. Thus, a 404 gets sent with correct CORS headers. However, the client application cannot read the 404, since the browser apparently treats this as a CORS failure, although it is not.

Comment: You can’t access the CORS preflight OPTIONS response headers from your frontend code. The browser doesn’t expose that OPTIONS response to your code. And if the response to the preflight OPTIONS request is anything other than a 200, 204 or other 2xx success code, then the preflight fails and the browser stops right there. So if your code causes the browser to send a preflight request to a URL which makes the server respond with a 404, then the rest of your code’s never gonna get executed—and your frontend code has no access to the status code of that OPTIONS response, nor its response headers

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much and posted this as an answer. I was just surprised that the browser apparently does not give any indication about what's wrong, just that there was an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem indeed was that my server responded with a `404` to the `OPTIONS` request. This made the browser interpret the CORS request to fail and thus not propagate any status codes.

To fix this, I modified the server to always respond with `200` to the CORS OPTIONS request. This makes the request succeed and the browser will perform the following GET/POST request, which then fails with `404` and returns the correct failure, which gets delivered to the frontend correctly.